# How to determine if two concave/convex shapes are at particular distance?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, geometry, polygon

I have to determine whether two concave/convex shapes are at distance d from each other . I know Separating Axis theorem might come handy in determining the distance , but that runs in O(n2) time ,  and I am looking for O(n) or O(nlogn) algorithm for any shape . I want to implement that for any two SVGs in javascript

Comment: It would be easier to help you with any piece of code.

Comment: "That runs in O(N²)": what is N ???

Comment: Please list the exact shape types to be supported.

Comment: I was following this http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/#sat-curve , N basically here is number of vertices's . Shapes that are supported are basically polygons with rounded edges , or mix of polygon circle ellipse hyperbola

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad and arduous problem.

To handle the most difficult cases (like ellipse/Bezier distance), you will need to somehow flatten the outlines so I recommend to flatten in all cases, and solve the problem for two polygons only.

Amazingly, you find little resources on the Web for the distance between two polygons.

Assuming that you are dealing with the inside of the shapes (and not just the outline), you will first have to check the polygons for void intersection (otherwise the distance is 0). I guess that this can be done in time O(N.Log(N)).

Then, if I am right, the closest distance between two polygons is the shortest of the closest distances of all vertices to the other polygon. If you construct the Voronoi diagram of both polygons (which is doable in time O(N.Log(N))), you get two planar subdivision, in which you can solve the point-location problem in time Log(N) per point.

All put together should lead to an O(N.Log(N)) solution. You will need a specialized Computational Geometry library to achieve this.

Comment: the closest distances can be vertex to edge though, so one would need to test line segments against a Voronoi map, which can theoretically get to N² I think, but only in a really contrived case (like when all edges cross almost all nodes of the subdivision tree)

Comment: @AntonKnyazyev: I don't think so. As both polygons are processed, it suffices to find the polygon element (vertex or edge) closest to every vertex of the other polygon. Hence a single type of query: point/polygon distance.

Comment: true, but I mean how can you find an edge of A closest to a vertex of B (and vice versa)? an edge can cross many Voronoi cells

Comment: @AntonKnyazyev: you didn't get my point. The closest distance between the polygons P and Q can occur a) between a vertex of P and a vertex of Q, or b) a vertex of P and an edge of Q, or c) an edge of P and a vertex of Q. But the distance between an edge of P and a vertex of Q is also the distance between a vertex of Q and an edge of P. So (c) is covered by (b) when swapping the roles of P and Q.

Comment: but you will still have to check edge-to-vertex distance for both P edge - Q vertex and Q edge - P vertex, so how do you check an edge against a vertex?

Comment: @AntonKnyazyev: I don't agree with you.

Comment: @Yves Daoust suppose a point P is just above mid of point of line segment AB , then shortest distance would be from mid point to P and not from A or B

Comment: @NEWUSER: why do you tell me that ? This is handled in the solution, by the Voronoi diagram.

Comment: I was just resolving my doubt , how to compute that distance from end points of line segment or just we have get some near point on line

Comment: @NEWUSER: the distance is to the polygon inside, not to the polygon vertices.